# How do I get my Downloads files back on my Mac?

Tags: finder, imac

I didn't lose the Downloads folder, just the files. When I clicked inside the folder, poof! Everything just disappeared, leaving nothing but an empty Downloads folder. They're not in Trash. When I do Command-R and load an older backup. Same thing! It shows me the files are there, but when I click to enter the folder, everything inside Downloads disappears, again.

I've lost the Downloads folder itself a few times before and was always able to drag it back into the window. Now the problem has a new wrinkle. Dang it! Anybody have a solution?

```
$ ls ~
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
DownloadsTHAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI
Dropbox
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Public
hewletts 2018.dvdcrtproj
iCloud Drive (Archive)

$ ls ~/Downloads
~$2018_ KATHYFORSTE.docx

Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls ~/Downloads
Downloads/
DownloadsTHAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI/
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls ~/Downloads
Downloads/
DownloadsTHAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI/
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls ~/Downloads

Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls -lF ~
total 0
drwx------@  4 harryhewlett  staff   128 Dec 20 06:39 Desktop/
drwx------@ 14 harryhewlett  staff   448 Feb  2  2018 Documents/
drwx------+  5 harryhewlett  staff   160 Dec 20 06:44 Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x   3 harryhewlett  staff    96 Dec  5 18:45 DownloadsTHAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI/
drwx------@ 43 harryhewlett  staff  1376 Dec 20 06:43 Dropbox/
drwx------@ 71 harryhewlett  staff  2272 Dec 24 04:09 Library/
drwx------+ 12 harryhewlett  staff   384 Sep 15 16:12 Movies/
drwx------+ 10 harryhewlett  staff   320 Oct 19 12:39 Music/
drwx------+ 14 harryhewlett  staff   448 Nov  2 22:22 Pictures/
drwxr-xr-x+  5 harryhewlett  staff   160 Jun 29  2015 Public/
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 harryhewlett  staff   320 Jun 14  2018 hewletts 2018.dvdcrtproj/
drwxr-xr-x  21 harryhewlett  staff   672 Feb  2  2018 iCloud Drive (Archive)/
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ 
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls -lF ~/Downloads
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 harryhewlett  staff  162 Oct 17 15:33 ~$2018_ KATHYFORSTE.docx
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ 

Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$ ls -l ~/Downloads*
/Users/harryhewlett/Downloads:
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 harryhewlett  staff  162 Oct 17 15:33 ~$2018_ KATHYFORSTE.docx

/Users/harryhewlett/DownloadsTHAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI:
Harrys-iMac:~ harryhewlett$
```

Comment: @grg - This is very different from the linked dupe.

Comment: Can you now post the output of the "wrong" `Downloads` folder?  You can do this by typing out `ls ~/Downloads` and then hitting the `Tab` key so it autocompletes the rest for you.  But I think we found the issue....your legit downloads folder is basically empty and there's another that's hosed up.

Comment: "THAT'S THE WAY THE WIND BLOWS BY JOHN LATINI, YPSILANTI, MI" when searched for showed up under Locations in Harry's iMac as an empty folder - nothing shows up in Downloads. The folder name is a song by John Latini that was entered in a song contest that I was help to administer several weeks ago - never had a folder by that name.

Comment: Try this....`ls -l ~/Downloads*`  I want to see what's going on in both folders....

Comment: @Allan The DownloadsTHATS... folder hasn't seen any activity since Dec 5th, it's probably just a folder which got named wrong.

Comment: Harry, can you *copy* a file into your Downloads folder? Would like to see whether it disappears again.

Comment: Ok..  That folder is empty.  Let's just remove it.  Type the following:  `rm -rf ~/DownloadsT`, then press `Tab`, then `Enter`

Comment: YES - can copy files to Downloads folder. No - they don't disappear.

Comment: DownloadsT removed.

Comment: While in downloads, I clicked on < in Finders and it took me to Recents and there were a whole bunch of files. Looked like Downloads & more. I'm wondering if my Mac is overwhelmed by the restored backup - Documents is still updating iCloud.

Comment: The Recents do not show up in Downloads when I click > back.

Comment: Don't remember seeing Recents before. Some sort of catch all. I guess it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please? And what is the references to iCloud, is there an iCloud migration running in the background?

Comment: Alan, I've got to put this on hold for a while - going to a family thing. Probably get back on this tomorrow. I really, sincerely, appreciate your assistance. Merry Xmas.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and typing `terminal`.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Type `cd ~/Downloads` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Type `open .` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I'm in. Just waiting for nohillside to respond.